# Problema al guardar la información de un archivo csv en un arreglo en C

Tags: c

Debo leer la información contenida dentro de un archivo externo en formato .csv y debo guardar cada fila del archivo en un arreglo. El código que tengo para realizar esa acción es el siguiente:

```
int generate_matrix(char *filename){

FILE *input1 = fopen(filename,"r");

if(input1 == NULL){
            
    return 1;
}

//counts the number of rows the file contains
int rows = 1;

char c = fgetc(input1);

while(!feof(input1)){
    
    if(c == '\n') rows++;
    
    c = fgetc(input1);
}

fclose(input1);

FILE *input2 = fopen(filename,"r");

char *students[rows];

char row[1000];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    
    fgets(row,1000,input2);
    
    row[strlen(row)] = '\0';
    
    students[i] = row;
    
    printf("%s", students[i]);
    
}

fclose(input2);

printf("\n\n");

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    printf("%s\n", students[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Este código es el que se supone que tendría que leer la linea de turno en el archivo y guardarlo en la posición correspondiente del arreglo:

```
char *students[rows];

char row[1000];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    
    fgets(row,1000,input2);
    
    row[strlen(row)] = '\0';
    
    students[i] = row;
    
    printf("%s", students[i]);
    
}
```

Al final de cada vuelta de bucle imprimo el valor que toma studenst[i] y efectivamente va leyendo línea por linea y aparentemente el código hace su trabajo.
Esta es la salida del programa hasta ese momento:

```
,TheGodfather,TokyoDrift,SpiritedAway,Tenet,TheGrandBudapestHotel,Frozen
ph20003,0,1,0,1,1,0
fc20015,1,1,0,1,0,0
cm19086,1,1,1,0,0,1
ve20008,0,1,0,1,0,0
mf19026,1,1,1,0,1,1
rc19106,0,0,1,1,0,1
ag19101,0,0,0,0,0,0
pg19065,0,1,0,0,0,0
lr19047,1,1,1,0,0,1
rf18025,0,1,0,0,0,0
aa19091,1,0,1,1,0,1
cc19089,0,1,1,1,0,0
hs20006,1,1,1,1,1,1
av19023,0,1,1,0,0,1
ft19004,0,0,0,0,0,1
dg17019,1,1,0,0,0,1
aa20047,0,1,0,0,0,0
rc19102,1,1,0,0,0,1
gr20035,1,0,1,0,0,0
rm19021,0,0,0,0,0,1
tq19002,0,1,0,0,0,1
ag17057,0,0,1,0,0,1
pc19060,1,1,1,0,0,1
hr18024,0,1,1,0,0,1
pm20072,1,1,0,0,0,1
tc20006,0,1,1,1,0,1
va17017,0,1,0,0,0,1
am18007,1,0,1,0,0,0
sm18038,0,1,0,0,0,0
cc20019,0,0,1,0,0,1
ff18023,0,1,0,0,0,0
vc17044,0,1,0,0,0,0
jm17015,0,1,0,1,0,1
ha19027,0,1,0,1,0,0
cd20017,0,1,1,0,0,1
mp19034,1,1,0,1,0,0
le19005,0,0,0,0,0,0
ma19074,0,1,0,0,0,1
cf20014,0,1,0,0,0,0
am19139,0,1,0,0,0,1
qj20001,0,0,0,0,0,0
pa19031,0,1,0,0,0,1
gs20027,0,1,1,0,0,1
ot20006,0,1,1,1,1,1
ze17002,0,1,1,0,0,1
ga19038,0,1,0,0,0,0
mh19029,0,1,0,0,0,1
fb19009,1,1,1,0,1,0
om20022,0,0,0,0,0,0
jg11008,0,1,1,0,0,0
gr12043,0,1,1,0,0,0
ar14078,0,1,1,0,0,1
vc20009,0,1,0,0,0,1
fa20011,0,1,0,0,0,0
mh19062,0,0,0,0,0,1
pr20028,0,0,0,0,1,1
ha17010,0,1,0,0,0,0
er20001,0,1,0,1,1,1
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
```

El problema es que cuando recorro al final el bucle para visualizar la información, me imprime información repetida, como si sólo hubiese leído un único registro.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    printf("%s\n", students[i]);
}
```

El resultado de lo anterior es:

```
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0 
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0 
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
bc18029,1,1,0,0,0,0
```

Corresponde la último registro del archivo. No sé porqué se está comportando de esa manera, no sé si sea algo que desconozco de la función fgets o que. Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea:

```c
char row[1000];
```

Le indica al compilador: *"Oye, reserva memoria para 1000 caracteres"* y ahí murió. El motivo del error **es que siempre se está usando el mismo bloque de memoria.**

Por ejemplo, en la primera iteración se lee el primer registro del archivo y luego se lo asigna al *array* `row`.

En la segunda iteración pasa lo mismo, se lee el segundo registro y se lo asigna al *array* `row` pero esto ocasiona que la información anterior que se había guardado se sobrescriba y esto va a pasar uno y otra vez. Por esa razón cuando se ejecute la última iteración, va a sobrescribir la información anterior y al final el *array* `row` se quedará con el último registro.

Así que el problema radica en esta línea:

```c
students[i] = row;
```

Una posible solución es reservar memoria con la función [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) en cada iteración:

```c
char *students[rows];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    //Reservamos memoria...
    char* row = malloc(1000* sizeof(char));
    fgets(row,1000,input2);
    
    //Por cierto, aquí te olvidaste de restarle menos uno: row[strlen(row) - 1]
    row[strlen(row)] = '\0';
    
    //Asignamos la dirección base del bloque devuelto por malloc en "students[i]"
    students[i] = row;
    
    printf("%s", students[i]);
    
}
```

**Nota:** Reservar `1000` bytes en cada iteración es una operación costosa, por lo que si en el archivo tiene un gran vólumen de datos puede ocasionar que el programa corra lento y consuma más memoria.